# Mono System.IO.File.Copy blocks my application

Tags: copy, mono, blocking

I have a question about the function System.IO.File.Copy under Raspberry pi with Mono.

If a USB stick is formatted with FAT or FAT32, the copy process blocks the complete application, although the copy functions runs in its own thread.
If the USB stick is formatted with exFAT or NTFS or the copy is running in its own application, there are no problems with the load.

Do any of you have an idea how I could work around this problem.

Comment: Mono is going away if you check the trend, https://github.com/mono/mono/graphs/contributors Please switch to .NET Core (.NET6 at this moment).

Comment: For the future, a switch to NET6 has already been planned if Forms work on Linux.
At the moment, a temporary solution to the above problem would be very helpful.

Comment: Mono and Mono WinForms have tons of known issues without fixes or workarounds, https://github.com/mono/mono/issues, so looking for temp solutions might waste you more time. Switching to .NET 6 and another UI framework that actively supports Linux is kind of the only feasible solution.